# File_get_content and CURL is not working, showing error of HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST

Tags: php, web-scraping

File get content and CRUL is not working on this link: http://xxx?text=I love my country.

If I put same URL on browser then It works.

Here is my code for File get content and CRUL

File get content

```
$result =   file_get_contents("http://xxxx?text=I love my country");
print_r($result);
```

CURL

```
$url = "http://xxx?text=I love my country";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r(data);
```

I also check file get contents on other URLs like

```
$result =   file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
```

and It is working fine on other URLs.

Is there is any other way from file get content and CURL to solve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
    $result = file_get_contents(str_replace(' ','+',"http://apidemo.theysay.io/api/v1/sentiment?text=I love my country"));
    print_r($result);
?>
```

You have to use `+` or `%20` to replace with blank space from url.

Or just use the following to encode url

```
<?php 
    $result = file_get_contents("http://apidemo.theysay.io/api/v1/sentiment?text=".urlencode("I love my country"));
    print_r($result);
?>
```